# Rewind functionality in Brightcove player

Tags: android, brightcove

In my app I implement the brightcove video player.
I am working on customizing brightcove.
I successfully implemented the play/pause option, and I am trying the same for the rewind option, but to no avail.

Here is my code

```
BrightcoveVideoView commonVideoView = (BrightcoveVideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.commonVideoViewId);
BrightcoveMediaController   mediaController = new BrightcoveMediaController(commonVideoView, R.layout.media_controllers);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `How can I solve this issue?`... **which** issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the seekTo method for achieving the same.

```
brightcoveVideoView.seekTo(value);
```